# Array and pointers input

Tags: c++

I'm facing a problem here. It is about inputs.

Edit: The program crashes everytime after i enter values to allocate them to each season. Btw, i'm self-learning c++ so…

```
#include <iostream>

const int Seasons = 4;
const char * Snames[Seasons] = { "Spring", "Summer", "Fall", "Winter" };

void fill(int*  a[], const int);

int main()
{
    int * expenses[Seasons];
    fill(expenses, Seasons);

    return 0;
}

void fill(int*  pa[], const int x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
    std::cout << "Enter " << Snames[i] << " expenses.";
    std::cin >> *pa[i];
    }
}
```

I know I can use string instead but may I know how do I go about solving this? I think the problem lies at *pa[i].

Thank you!

Comment: Rephrase your question and is this a homework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement

```
std::cin >> *pa[i];
```

dereferences an uninitialized pointer.
You don't need `int*` pointers for this case at all. Just change your array and function signature to

```
 int expenses[Seasons];

 void fill(int*  pa, const int x)
```

and use

```
 std::cin >> pa[i]; // Note no dereferencing
```